# How to highlight entire full line in code mirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am able to change the background of a range of lines in code mirror with the below code:

```
javaEditor.markText(
    { line: 0, ch: 0 },
    { line: 2, ch: 0 },
    {
      atomic: true,
      handleMouseEvents: true,
      css: "background-color:lightgrey",
      selectRight: true,
      readOnly: true,
    }
  );
```

But, the highlight is working only for the characters and not the **whole** line, as shown below:

[image]

I want the highlight to look like this:

[image]

Comment: When you select the lines with your mouse, does it behave the same way?

Cause codemirror sets the nackground styling for those selections via Javascript upon selection, maybe you miss a handler or you are missing some css.

Comment: The second screenshot was basically mouse selection

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to highlight lines according to `class`.

Create a class:

```css
.mark {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

In JS to highlight line 5

```js
cm.addLineClass(line-1, "wrap", "mark");
```